# Sorting random array multiple times with different selection methods

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to test how fast different sorting methods are for an array. I have the sorting methods in a different file, and I am trying to sort the array 10 times and find the time, but I am having trouble getting a new random number array every time.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static int[] makeArray(int x) {
    int[] a = new int [x];
    for( int i = 0; i < x; i ++) {
        Random r = new Random(1234);
        a[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 100;
    int [] arr = makeArray(x);
    for(int i = 0; i  <x; i++) {
        int[] copy = new int [x];
        copy[i] = arr[i];
    }
    long t = System.nanoTime();
    Sorts.SelectionSort(arr);
    long y = System.nanoTime();
    long totalTime = y-t;
    System.out.println("time = " + totalTime); 
    long z = System.nanoTime();
    Sorts.SelectionSort(copy);
    long w = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("time = " + w-z);
}
```

Comment: Put the `Random` initialization before the loop.  If you want different but repeatable array values, just change the random seed: e.g., `Random r = new Random(1234*nonce);`, where `nonce` is some one-time value you'll have to set up.  For more unpredictable values, use some sort of time function or other source of "randomness" to build the seed.

Comment: For this particular application, it may be beneficial to have the same seed each time so you are truly comparing sort times with the same array. But like @PaulLambert said, you need to move the `Random r = new Random(1234);` outside of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this :

```
public static int[] makeArray(int x) {
    int[] a = new int [x];
    Random r = new Random(1234);
    for( int i = 0; i < x; i ++) {
        a[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 100;
    int [] arr = makeArray(x);
    for(int i = 0; i  <x; i++) {
        int[] copy = new int [x];
        copy[i] = arr[i];
    }
    long t = System.nanoTime();
    Sorts.SelectionSort(arr);
    long y = System.nanoTime();
    long totalTime = y-t;
    System.out.println("time = " + totalTime); 
    long z = System.nanoTime();
    Sorts.SelectionSort(copy);
    long w = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("time = " + w-z);
}
```

If you put the Random r = new Random(1234); in the loop you initialize r at every turn.